# To Get focus on both Listview and image button?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

In a Custom ListView extending Cursoradapter, I need both Listview and image button to get focussed. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own **OnTouchListener** for **ListView** which conditional return values. If you return **TRUE** from **onTouch**, the system will assume that the **onTouch** was handled and it won't handle it by itself. If you return **FALSE** from **onTouch**, system will assume that the **OnTouchListener** did not handle the touch events and will do further processing. This way you can manage how the touch / click should work with **ImageButton** in a **ListView**.

I don't know what exactly your implementation is. But it may give you a little idea...

```
boolean pressedImageButton = false;
myListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(action)
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float positionX = event.getRawX();
            float positionY = event.getRawY();
            if(some conditions with positionX and positionY)
                pressedImageButton = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(pressedImageButton)
                myImageButton.performClick(); // or whatever action you want to perform on that ImageButton
            pressedImageButton = false;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi Hemendra Sharma , i m new to android.I can't understand what you are saying. If possible can you share any example?

Comment: thank you. I solved that problem without touch listener, gave android:descendability="blockDescendents" and                       called performitemclick() function in onclicklistener of button, so that it calls, onitemclicklistener of list view.